# React unit tests not failing when test suite is ran

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

I created a unit test for a React component. The first test should pass if and email address is not provided and we alert the user that one wasn't. This passes both as a separate test and when the whole suite runs. The second test should pass if an email is provided but not a password and alerts the user with a message that a password needs to be provided.

The issue I'm seeing is if I tell the password unit test to check that the alert was that an email was not provided. In this case if I run the test separately it fails, saying that an email needs to be provided as expected. However if I run this as a suite with the email check ran first then the password check ran separately the password check passes when it shouldn't as the email address is provided and the alert message should be about no password provided. If I run the test suite with the password check first and the email check separate the password check fails as I expect. Depending on the order the tests are ran I get different results.

I've tried running the options --env=jsdom --watchAll=false --coverage both via command line, with the npm config from package.json, and using the webstorm run configurations, but they all produce the same result.

The unit test:

```
import React from 'react';
import { configure, shallow } from 'enzyme';
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16.3';
import SignInForm from '../components/SignInForm';
//import { mount, shallow, render } from 'enzyme';

configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });

test('Errors when no email is input', () => {
  jest.spyOn(window, 'alert').mockImplementation(() => {});
  const wrapper = shallow(<SignInForm />);
  wrapper.find('input#email_address').simulate('change', {target: { value: '' }});
  wrapper.find('button').simulate('click');
  expect(window.alert).toHaveBeenCalledWith('Email address is required to sign in');
});

test('Errors when no password is input', () => {
  jest.spyOn(window, 'alert').mockImplementation(() => {});
  const wrapper = shallow(<SignInForm />);
  wrapper.find('input#email_address').simulate('change', {target: { value: "Tst@test.com" }});
  wrapper.find('button').simulate('click');
  expect(window.alert).toHaveBeenCalledWith('Email address is required to sign in');
```

});

The signin form web component:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

export default class SignInForm extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {email_address: '', password: ''};
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
}

handleChange(field, event) {
    this.setState({[field]: event.target.value});
}

handleSubmit(event) {
    if (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
    const {email_address, password} = this.state;
    if (email_address === '') {
        alert("Email address is required to sign in");
        return;
    } else if (password === '') {
        alert("Password is required to sign in");
        return;
    }
}

render() {
    return (
        <form id="signInForm">
            <div className="form-group">
                <label htmlFor="email_address">Email address</label>
                <input type="email" className="form-control" name="email_address" id="email_address"
                    aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter email" onChange={this.handleChange.bind(null, 'email_address')} />
            </div>
            <div className="form-group">
                <label htmlFor="password">Password</label>
                <input type="password" className="form-control" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" onChange={this.handleChange.bind(null, 'password')} />
            </div>
            <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary" onClick={this.handleSubmit.bind(this)}>Submit</button>
      </form >
    );
}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because jest is internally keeping track of everything that is happening. If it runs once (from your first test), it "remembers" that when the second test runs. I bet if you change the ordering of those two tests, they will pass. But this is not the real solution.

You have to `jest.clearAllMocks()` before you run every test. You should scope all your tests into one `describe` block and run a `beforeEach` inside so you can automatically run `jest.clearAllMocks()` before each test.

```
describe('unit tests', () => ({
  beforeEach(() => {
    jest.clearAllMocks()
  })
  // test('Errors when no email is input', () => { unit tests here
})
```